# Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\teach\mongo\index.php on line 11 - Mongodb + XAMPP

Tags: php, mongodb, apache, xampp, nosql

I downloaded Mongodb - Installed -> create bat file -> create Data/db folder -> working fine in cmd


Then, Downloaded PHP Driver from GitHib Version 5.3 TS VC6.

copied "php_mongo.dll" in "xampp/php/ext"

Then edited "xampp/php/php.ini" - extension=php_mongo.dll

Restarted Apache - stop and start

**Check**
[http://localhost/xampp/] -> phpinfo() -> showing "mongo"

I run the below code and getting ERROR
"**Fatal error**:  Class 'MongoClient' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\teach\mongo\index.php on line 11"
Again and again

Please help

**Testing RUNNING**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>C MongoDB Insert</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
echo '<pre>';
// Connect to the MongoD with defaults which are localhost and port 27017)  
$m = new MongoClient();
echo '<br />Connection var dump below <br />';
var_dump($m);
// Use a DataBase (will be created if it doesn't exist)
echo '<br />database var dump below <br />';
$db = $m->demodb;
var_dump($db);
// Use a Collection (will be created if it doesn't exist)
$coll = $db->democoll;
echo '<br />Collection var dump below <br />';
var_dump($coll);
$coll->insert(array(
    'key1' => 'Another Row',
    'AnArray' => array(
        'embedded array value 1',
        'embedded array value 2'
    ),
    'embeddedDoc1' => array(
        'embedDoc1Key1' => 'Embedded text in Doc1',
        'embedDoc1Key2' => 'More text for fun'
    )
    ));
    echo '<h2 style="color:red">Below is our Document</h2>';
$myDoc = $coll->findOne(array('key1' => 'Another Row'));
print_r($myDoc);
echo '</pre>';
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of the PHP driver did you download from Github? Most of these are very old (and quite likely predate the introduction of the MongoClient class). I would suggest downloading the latest PHP driver (currently 1.4.5) from the [current PHP download page](https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html).

Comment: I used mongo-1.1.4.zip for 5.3 TS VC6
As suggested, I'll try New XAMPP for PHP 5.4.__
Otherwise, Is there any prob in my methods?

Comment: If you are are using the (very old) 1.1.4 driver, the `MongoClient` class is not available. You could try using the class `Mongo` instead, but it is [highly discouraged](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongo.php). You need at least the 1.3.x PHP driver for `MongoClient`, but are best to upgrade your XAMPP to PHP 5.4 and install the latest PHP 1.4.x driver.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked with upgraded xampp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every part of program is right and working after upgrading PHP version

We need at least the 1.3.x PHP driver for MongoClient, but are best to upgrade your XAMPP to PHP 5.4 and install the latest PHP 1.4.x driver. - Thanks @stennie